# javascript change position of element without string concatenation

Tags: javascript, dom, css-position, string-concatenation

Most of the answers to this question give solution similar to:

```
let x_pos=42, y_pos=43;
var d = document.getElementById('yourDivId');
d.style.position = "absolute";
d.style.left = x_pos+'px';
d.style.top = y_pos+'px';
```

but isn't it expensive, just to change the postion, to convert the integers to string and do some concatenations?

I think the browser will probably do exactly the reverse calculations to get the integer values again.

Comment: Why do you think they're "expensive string concatenations"?

Comment: string concatenations needs more cpu cycles as just an assignment, the unit scaling, could be done in a way like d.setX(42, "px"); which would be still faster than the aproach above

Comment: Browsers are really well optimised these days. Unless you're doing something crazy with your code a couple of string concatenations aren't going to be CPU expensive.

Comment: Well it ain't going to happen since you need the number and unit. Highly doubt that small concatenation is going to be the slowness in your code.  `premature optimization`

Comment: The amount of time the browser takes to parse the string is negligible compared to the amount of time it spends in order to relayout and repaint the affected region, and even that is so fast in normal circumstances that you will never notice it (unless your document is very, very complex).

Comment: But I think the argument, that for the modern hardware it is negligible is not convincing, maybe you want to run the website on a very limited hardware, for such cases it will be not negligible. What is also the reason to not implement a direct way?

Comment: @neoexpert *maybe you want to run the website on a very limited hardware*: that's a new argument you should perhaps have mentioned in the question. Anyway, i think the operation is negligible on such devices too (unless it's using IE <= 7, [hardly used](https://gs.statcounter.com/browser-market-share#monthly-202010-202110-bar) anymore). The [link](https://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-fast-string-concatenation/) in my answer explains this convincingly enough imho.

Answer (score 0):

It's not that expensive to [concatenate strings in modern browsers](https://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-fast-string-concatenation/) nowadays. Here's a factory to move an element to a(nother) position, using a small helper for converting numbers to units.

```js
// factory to avoid recreating [number2Unit] for every call and 
// and delegate the actual styling to small methods.
function moveElToFactory(ux = `px`, uy = `px`) {
  const number2Unit = (nr, unit) => `${nr}${unit}`;
  const moveX = (el, x, unit) => el.style.left = number2Unit(x, unit);
  const moveY = (el, y, unit) => el.style.top = number2Unit(y, unit);
  
  return (el, x, y, uX = ux, uY = uy) => {
    el.style.position = `absolute`;
    y && moveY(el, y, uY);
    x && moveX(el, x, uX);
  }
}

// demo
const moveElTo = moveElToFactory();
setTimeout(() => {
  const [d1, d2, d3] = [
    document.querySelector('#div1'),
    document.querySelector('#div2'), 
    document.querySelector('#div3')]
  moveElTo(d1, 42, 43);
  d1.textContent += ` [x, y] ${d1.style.left}, ${d1.style.top}`;
  moveElTo(d2, 15, 50, `vw`, `%`);
  d2.textContent += ` [x, y] ${d2.style.left}, ${d2.style.top}`;
  moveElTo(d3, ...[,35,,`%`]); 
  d3.textContent += ` [x, y] 0, ${d3.style.top}`; }, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="div1">where am I (div#div1)?</div>
<div id="div2">And where am I (div#div2)?</div>
<div id="div3">And I (div#div3) am where?</div>
```